# Flat to multi-level nested data

Tags: sql, postgresql

In BQ, I have used `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(...` to restructure some flat data but wanted to go a level further: create another array of records within an array of records.
Although STRUCT does not exist in PostgreSQL, I am interested how one would tackle that there too.

Considering the flat data:

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT 'ABC' company, 'adress1' address, 'name1' name, 'email1' email, 'work' ph_type, '+123' ph_nr
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC' company, 'adress1' address, 'name1' name, 'email1' email, 'cell' ph_type, '+987'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF' company, 'adress2' address, 'name2' name, 'email2' email, 'work' ph_type, '+127'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF' company, 'adress2' address, 'name2' name, 'email2' email, 'cell' ph_type, '+988'
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ' company, 'adress3' address, 'name3' name, 'email3' email, 'work' ph_type, '+456'
)
```

I can nest `contact` like so

```
SELECT company, address, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, email, ph_type, ph_nr)) contact
FROM a
GROUP BY company, address
ORDER BY 1
```

but how can I nest, **in the same select statement**, `phones` as well (array of records within `contact`) ?

The JSON representation would look like - for the first contact:

```
[
 {
  "company": "ABC",
  "address": "adress1",
  "contact": [
    {
      "name": "name1",        
      "email": "email1",
      "phone": [
        {
         "ph_type": "work",
         "ph_nr": "+123"
        },
        {
         "ph_type": "cell",
         "ph_nr": "+987"
        }
    },
   ...
```

This can probably be done with a `WITH` clause or subselect to process the aggregations sequentially but not sure this would perform well (data read twice ?).

I have 600M records to parse daily so wondering about the most efficient way.

**EDIT**: corrected name definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is two levels of aggregation.

However, the question itself confuses me, because the query uses `name` but that is not defined in the data.

Here is an example of what to do:

```
SELECT company, address, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(email, phones)) as contact
FROM (SELECT company, name, address, email, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ph_type, ph_nr)) as phones
      FROM a
      GROUP BY company, name, address, email
     ) a
GROUP BY company, address
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: My bad - you are right, I have corrected the query. I was wondering if subquery is the only way to go. Concern is performance on large datasets.

Comment: performance metrics: I used a partial dataset I had - 49M records (5GB) - and it took 294s to process when having ORDER BY on both ARRAY_AGG, and 104s without any. Ordering on all is more for convenience so will skip. Still hoping to decrease query time though.

Comment: @YannickEinsweiler . . . Two levels of aggregation is going to be expensive on a large table.